How to allow expired JWTs on a specific ASP.NET Core 8.0 endpoint without affecting other routes?
In our ASP.NET Core 8.0 app, we have the following endpoint:
[HttpPost("login-refresh-token")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<AccessTokenDto>> RefreshTokenLogin([FromBody] RefreshTokenRequestModel requestModel)
{
    ...
}

This endpoint requires a refresh token in the request body and an expired JWT access token in the authorization header. The expired access token is used for validation purposes before issuing a new access token.
To achieve this, we tried to use the [Authorize] attribute and override the JWT Bearer options as follows:
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                // Custom logic to skip expiration for certain routes
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                // Specify the route that allows expired tokens
                if (path.StartsWithSegments("/login-refresh-token"))
                {
                    context.Options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false; // Allow expired token
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };

However, this approach introduces a problem: expired tokens intermittently work on other endpoints as well, likely because the TokenValidationParameters object is shared across requests.
I'm looking for a simple alternative solution that:

Does not require parsing the JWT manually.
Avoids creating a new principal for validation.
Allows expired tokens only on the required route while enforcing token expiration on all other routes.

Is there a clean and reliable way to achieve this behavior?

Perhaps set [AllowAnonymous] on this refresh endpoint? and handle the refresh outside JwtBearer?

@ToreNestenius that is what we are currently doing, but was looking for a cleaner solution

I don't think you will find any libraries that will help you here, because the spec clearly states that an expired JWT must never be processed, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.4
The most common way to handle this is to have a second Refresh Token that can be used to renew a JWT. The Refresh Token is just another JWT with longer expiry time. This is for example how Auth0 does, and this approach will force changes on all your clients.
Or you can have a Soft Expiry" in your JWT (a custom claim) that all API endpoints uses for validation, except the the refresh token endpoint. This approach will force changes on all your API Gateways.
This final solution is to parse the JWT manually, even if you explicitly wrote that you don't want to do that. But that will make the solution transparent for both your clients and your API Gateways (in case they are spread out over micro services and are complicated to update).

Thanks for the answer. We did end up parsing/validating manually.

Feel free to upvote or accepts answer if you found it helpful. :-)
